# What is branching and iteration in an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

This is my first question here. I was looking over the curriculum of year 5 mathematics in my country and came across this "Content description". (from http://victoriancurriculum.vcaa.vic.edu.au/mathematics/curriculum/f-10?y=5&s=NA&s=MG&s=SP&layout=2)

Follow a mathematical algorithm involving branching and repetition (iteration) (VCMNA194)

Can someone explain what branching and repetition mean here? The repetition part I am fine with, but the branching part I cannot picture concretely.

If you could give an example of branching within an algorithm, it would be very helpful. I looked up mathematics dictionaries, but with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've noticed I got marked down :-( If my question is a duplicate, I would be very appreciative if I could see where else this question was asked. Or if this is the wrong forum for such a question, it would be helpful if I knew where to go for this sort of information. My google and dictionary search didn't get me very far. This is a topic I'm supposed to be across, so it won't do for me not to find an answer (somewhere). Sorry for the intrusion or inadvertent breach of etiquette :-( (If there is something I need to know, I'm all ears).

Comment: It looks like they are referring to [this type of branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)). And they give an example deeper in your link: "manipulating sets of numbers using a given rule, for example, if a number is even halve it; if a number is odd, subtract 1 then halve it"

Comment: In a nutshell, "branching" is associated in computer science to "if then else" instructions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting above:

It looks like they are referring to this type of branches. And they give an example deeper in your link: "manipulating sets of numbers using a given rule, for example, if a number is even halve it; if a number is odd, subtract 1 then halve it" – orole yesterday

In a nutshell, "branching" is associated in computer science to "if then else" instructions... – Jean Marie yesterday